# How can I make an alarm circuit which senses both cutting and shorting the wire?

Tags: security, wire-loop

I have searched Google top to bottom the only circuit which fullfills my requirements is a wire break or wire loop security alarm as shown in figure 1. I soon realised that if the robber shorts the wire before cutting it (as the situation exposes the loop) my system can't sense it and thealarm will not turn on as in figure 2. Can some one tell me how to make it sense a short circuit as well?

[image]

[image: fig 2]

Comment: expect to see resistance when the circuit is normal

Comment: I AM not a professional electronic technician so if you explain little more about how to make a circuit which detect the decrease in resistance

Comment: If the security wire is resistance wire, then any change from the say 10 Ohm resistance is either tampering or a significant temperature change.  Constantan and manganin have very low thermal coefficients. Mangarin has a resistance 100 times that of Constantan

Comment: I was involved in a high security design that needed to detect cases like this. We were going to use something similar to Time-Domain-Reflectometry. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer) Basically sending pulses along the line and measuring the time it took for them to arrive at the other end. If they arrived early or late, we knew the line had been tampered with. Ultimately, they traded the additional security for a less expensive design closer to what the other answers propose.

Comment: That's sounds great can you please tell me more about that time domain reflectometer circuit or any reference to the circuit...?

Comment: Make the wires inaccessible, think of a safe, the mechanical parts that control the lock are all on the inside.

Comment: It's a very complicated solution. Not trying to gatekeep or anything, but it's a lot of work. (This security system was for a nuclear facility and they decided it wasn't worth the trouble, lol) The tricky part is that the signals are moving at nearly the speed of light, so the system has to be very fast to measure them correctly. There are tricks that might help, like splitting the signal between the sense loop and a reference and then comparing the two....

Answer (score 10):

Building on @jsotola's comment.  A window comparator coupled with a resistance in the sense line would allow the circuit to detect the open and shorted condition.
[Understanding a window comparator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426227/understanding-a-window-comparator)
[image]
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html
For example in the image above, if you used a 1kΩ resistor from Vin to Vcc and then your *loop* incorporated another 1kΩ resistor (physically out in the loop somewhere), that would create a voltage of 1/2Vcc, which is between the 1/3Vcc and 2/3Vcc limits.  In this state, the output would be high.
If someone opened the wire, the voltage would go **above the 2/3Vcc limit** and the output would go low.
If they shorted the wire, then the voltage would go **below the 1/3Vcc limit** and the output would go low.

Answer (score 6):

The thing you’re asking about is called in the trade a ‘supervised loop’. This can be implemented using a known load at the end of the line, such as a resistor or a Zener diode as well as other anti-tamper and fault detection methods.

[This page](https://technolysis-hts.gr/knowledge-base/designing-a-fully-supervised-loop-fsl-eol-alarm-system/) gives an example of a Fully Supervised Loop:

[image]

So the supervision detects the following:

- 2.2k - normal
- 6.9k - alarm
- open - tamper

And I'll add, since you asked:

- closed (shorted) - also tamper

The control panel for such a system monitors line resistance. A possible design for this would be:

- a circuit that feeds a fixed current to the line (current source), or has a known resistance to a known voltage
- an ADC to monitor the voltage developed across the line

My thought would be that using an ADC instead of fixed comparators allows flexibility in how the circuit is set up. Since most microcontrollers feature multiple ADC channels, there's no additional hardware needed to do it this way.

Here's a setup that treats the sensed line as a voltage divider ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAnWvcGm7kChT8qQuJ3AoeYPuGIpeI2hnEBnST2KE5CrVH0AzAIYAbVQzbrhVPbn56qVY2YtdrikHY9UaKyJcEaUWFPSH4hJSdTcwCwKUEQsHkEyJBnGIB3DRSBCKg2LPc8pIU8-yy46VkaKpECnQ93GTqK5L0S73rKkHb45vzCoJ7tJtly0PttL37x6dlsQlqBiZyFnjKAtY8tsvA06Issrf6aqhmJU49LvEcE8QAlbiobp4FboaRbmAR6nZDLjZZAH-F7ufwAc1e7gBCG0jjYAAcKH1ZAg%20sl6PCgS9%20milhDkdJknjBPh9OMSbjkucAB4gQhwcDYciEbAQGQ%20SQgAAqAHsADqqACuAGE2HSGeyEPxCLDwAhyPw4iAAIIAERFgoAkgA7BFCgAu4t49Aw2jAeCQGGItC5KpMRg4AFtBew6SgEFbyCgyCAXkqFPbHS7VChjRzBJQ5BAPfQAzyjE6EQwOK7jcIbR6qLhRAg41zuYnk6nQ8bsJbwHhtDRPZWbfGAOQAZQAFryOAaGAATQUmACWOoYDeNTGZle95CSnOVAFEdT3VAB5AyCgAyA4sQA)):

[image]

In the normal condition, the sensed voltage is 2.5V since the EOL resistor is the same as the pull-up at the control panel. Your uC software would monitor this voltage, and if it's 5V you know the line was cut; 0V you know the line was shorted, and some value above 2.5V but less than 4.5V you know one of the alarm switches opened but the line is still good.

That said, a smart burglar could defeat this by injecting the voltage if they could gain physical access to both sides of the loop.

Comment: Where can find this type of system or if there is no readymade circuit then can you help me with schematic diagram

Comment: Since some of this work can be related to life safety (like fire alarms), your solution will need to comply with applicable codes.   The alarm system you choose would be best if it had line supervision built in.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way?  Wire up a relay that has both normally open and normally closed contacts.